# SQL SELECT (beginner)

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have 2 tables:

**Departament**

```
id_dep, name_dep
```

**Employee**

```
id_dep, salary
```

I want to get name of the departments where ALL the salaries are less than 7000. I have to create a `SELECT` statement. I am a beginner at SQL and I'm sorry if I'll lose your time, but I need help.

I have a solution, but I don't know if is good or not:

```
SELECT name_dep
FROM departments
WHERE employee.salary < 7000
MINUS
SELECT name_dep
FROM departments
WHERE employee.salary >= 7000
```

Comment: Have you tried to read any manual?

Comment: Check out GROUP BY and SUM. And JOIN.

Comment: I tried , I have a solution , but I don't know if is good or not : SELECT name_dep FROM departments WHERE employee.salary< 7000 MINUS SELECT name_dep FROM departments WHERE employee.salary >=7000

Comment: If you have tried something, then write that in your question.

Comment: Please **do not** put code samples or sample data into comments - since you cannot format it, it's **extremely hard** to read it.... Instead: **update** your question by editing it to provide that additional information! Thank you.

Comment: Please tag dbms product used. (Since you have product specific MINUS there.)

Comment: `minus` is fine for this. I doubt that Oracle will do anything different compared to the `not exists` solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it using `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT id_dep , name_dep
FROM department AS d
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                  FROM employee AS e
                  WHERE e.id_dep = d.id_dep AND e.salary >=  7000)
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding `JOINs` to the original `MINUS` attempt:

```
SELECT d.name_dep
FROM departments d
  JOIN employee e ON d.id_dep = e.id_dep
WHERE e.salary < 7000
MINUS
SELECT d.name_dep
FROM departments d
  JOIN employee e ON d.id_dep = e.id_dep
WHERE e.salary >= 7000
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `NOT EXISTS` or `EXISTS`, try this code block for your problem.

**NOT EXISTS**

```
select d.name_dep
  from department as d
 where not exists (select 1
          from employee as e
         where e.id_dep = d.id_dep
           and e.salary >= 7000)
 group by d.dep_name
```

**EXISTS**

```
select d.name_dep
  from department as d
 where exists (select 1
          from employee as e
         where e.id_dep = d.id_dep
           and e.salary < 7000)
 group by d.dep_name
```

Answer (score 0):

You can group by department and check for max of salary in group:

```
select d.id_dep, d.name_dep
from department d
join employee e on d.id_dep = e.id_dep
group by d.id_dep, d.name_dep
having max(e.salary) < 700
```